# How to fix grub menu when restarting ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu, syslinux, ubuntu-one-windows

I am a new Ubuntu user, I replace my windows 10 with Ubuntu because I only want to use Ubuntu..but every time I power on my laptop it shows menu to select ubuntu and two more options .. please tell me how to fix this .. it's called grub menu maybe.! I cannot post image it's like

```
                                GNU GRUB VERSION 2.04
```

*Ubuntu
Advanced option for Ubuntu
UEFI Firmware Settings

Please tell me this is how ubuntu restarts or its only in my laptop.

Comment: That's common. No need to worry about it. In some cases you need to select that Advanced option. That's why it always shows.

Comment: Maybe you can just reset GRUB_TIMEOUT to 0, in file /etc/default/grub, then run sudo update-grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that menu is called GRUB Loader and it's responsible to boot your system with Ubuntu. If you would have had a dual boot system then you could have selected which operating system to boot up with, from this GRUB menu.

If you don't want to see GRUB loader menu you can follow these steps:

1. Go to this file: `/etc/default/grub`. This file has all the configuration for the GRUB loader.
2. After opening this file comment out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and
   `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` and then apply the changes by running
   this command:

   sudo update-grub

If can also follow this documentation, it might be helpful: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/ubuntu-1404-hide-grub-menu/

Comment: thankyou , that worked, I have only ubuntu in my system and it irritates everytime i switch on my laptop.